# How to authenticate without writing credentials in the actual code?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication

noob question: in a setting where I have some Node.js code needing to call a service which requires authentication, how do I pass sensible data in a secure way?
This problem arose because I'm trying to send emails, but I would like to know a general strategy to avoid writing the plain credentials in the code, or at least in which direction I should go

Comment: The dupe I posted above talks about hiding *database* credentials which is essentially the same concept for hiding *any* service credentials.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!